# find if string is a path

Tags: python, string, path, substring

I am working in python. my problem is I have several strings and I have to detect which part of them look like a path and then normalize the ones that are actual paths.

e.g. I have several different strings like follows :

1. ..\..\..\Workspace

2. C:\source\Workspace

3. -B..\..\source

4. -build..\..\work\source..\workspace

5. -HD:\abc\bds\Workspace

Basically some strings are paths straightaway and some have a trailing - attached to them. The length of option string is variable.

In the above example strings 3, 4, 5 contain a path string pre-attached with an option -B, -build, -H respectively.

 The problem is how to detect from the above examples, which part of the string is a path and which is not. The options are not fixed so I can't just check given string's head for pre-specified options.

 The only way to go forward is taking the sub-string starting from .. or one character before : (e.g. C: or D:).

So the question is that is there any generalized way of doing this or does python provide any function to take truncated portion of a string starting  from any particular position ?

any answer which satisfies above 5 examples is cool even though it is kinda overfitting.

The code that I am currently using for e.g. 2 and 5 is : `path = path[path.find(':')-1:]`
and for others its `path = path[path.find('.'):]`. But this is not generalized and uncool. So I am looking for a better algorithm or solution.

Comment: as is `re.split` or perhaps even `str.split`

Comment: split on what? split needs some character to be split on

Comment: You can not detect pathnames. For example on linux the path is allowed to contain any characters except '\0'. The only characters that are handled specially are '\0' because this terminates the string and '/' is used as a path component separator but this latter fact doesn't really matter/help...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a known list of options, I don't think you can have 100% reliable algorithm.

If we go with some reasonable guesses, I could think of something like this:

- if it does not start with -, it is a path
- if it starts with -, remove the first letter and use os.path.exists on remainder and if it returns true then you have path
- repeat above until you get to non-alphanumeric character

Some cases where this breaks down:

- we really have a path, but it does not exist in the file system
- we might eat the drive letter, and check if path exists on wrong drive
- if option can contain non-alphanumeric characters
- parameter is a file or folder in current directory

Comment: yes. Considering its windows the algorithm breaks at several places and this is a hard problem because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think a tool that you will need are the list slicing mechanics

we initialize a string:

```
string = "a/b/c/d"
```

if we want to access for example the **first** two elements then we would do:

```
sub_string = string[:2]
```

if we want to access the **last** two elements then we would use:

```
sub_string = string[-2:]
```

more on list slicing http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yes the code that I am currently using path = path[path.find(':')-1:] for examples 2 and 5. and for others its path = path[path.find('.'):]

Answer (score 0):

Use this function I created:

```
import os

string_1 = 'adsflk;ajewqpfoiewjqfpowijapfeiojC:\Python27'

def parse_path(string):
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        new_string = string.split(string[:count], 1)
        if os.path.exists(new_string[1]):
            return new_string
            break
```

Running that `parse_path` function with `string_1` returns `'C:\Python27'`.  Just send the function any of those strings and it should work.  Good luck!  Ask questions in the comments.

Comment: this one consumes a lot more time than the code that I have written in the question.

Comment: You're asking for a generalized version, this is one that answers your question.  It works across various path names and types and isn't uncool like you say your solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do it?

```
import os

possibles = [
"..\..\..\Workspace",
"C:\source\Workspace",
"-B..\..\source",
"-build..\..\work\source..\workspace",
"-HD:\abc\bds\Workspace "
]

paths = []
for p in possibles:
    if p[0] == '-':
        if ':' in p:
            p = p[p.index(':')-1:]
        else:
            cut = 2
            while not os.path.exists(p) and p:
                p = p[cut:]
                cut+=1
    if p: paths.append(p)
```